# Fazer uma condição para verificar URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, estou usando *CodeIgniter* para desenvolver meu website, estou tentando verificar em qual controlador o usuário está navegando, por exemplo, tenho a área de login e cadastro, se o usuário estiver navegando na página de login quero que mostre o botão de cadastro, e se ele estiver navegando na página de cadastro quero que mostre o botão de login.
Eu estou tentando fazer isto na `navbar` para não ter que criar dois arquivos diferentes apenas para criar um simples botãozinho. Bom esta seria uma forma normal de se fazer:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['url'] === 'login') {
  echo '<li>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">
            Cadastro
            </a>
          </p>
        </li>';
}

if ($_GET['url'] === 'cadastro') {
  echo '<li>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">
            Login
            </a>
          </p>
        </li>';
}
```

E no *CodeIgniter* como posso proceder para fazer isso?

Comment: Qual versão do CodeIgniter?

Comment: Eu estou usando a versão 2.1.2, eu estava seguindo um tutorial no youtube, sou iniciante então baixei a mesma versão do tutorial.

Comment: Vou tentar postar uma resposta, mas é do CI3, mas não deve mudar muito

Comment: Ta ok, qualquer coisa eu mudo para CI3.

Comment: Pelo que olhei parece que é igual no CI2 ;) pode testar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O CodeIgniter assim como muitos frameworks php funciona com Controllers e Views, no caso do CI3 ficaria assim:

login:

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Login';
            $this->load->view('headerview', $data);
            $this->load->view('menuview', array( 'islogin' => true ));
            $this->load->view('loginview'); //isto exibe o view do login
            $this->load->view('footerview');
    }
}
```

Cadastro:

```
<?php
class Cadastro extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Cadastro';
            $this->load->view('headerview', $data);
            $this->load->view('menuview', array( 'islogin' => false ));
            $this->load->view('cadastroview'); //isto exibe o view do cadastro
            $this->load->view('footerview');
    }
}
```

Ao acessar `http://localhost/ci/index.php/login/` você seria irá visualizar o resultado do controller login

Ao acessar `http://localhost/ci/index.php/cadastro/` você seria irá visualizar o resultado do controller cadastro

No view *menuview* é que você terá que fazer o ajuste, veja que passe o `array( 'isLogin' => ... )` em ambos como true e false, então ele deve ficar assim:

```
if ($islogin) {
  echo '<li>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">
            Cadastro
            </a>
          </p>
        </li>';
} else {
  echo '<li>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">
            Login
            </a>
          </p>
        </li>';
}
```

Note que o `$islogin` representa o `array( 'isLogin' => ... )` do controller.

Para mais detalhes veja a documentação:

- http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html
- http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Note que as URLs no CI3 ficam assim `http://localhost/ci/index.php/...` se você quiser "remover" o `index.php` você pode usar .htaccess assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Documentação:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: Ok, vou fazer os testes e volto com os resultados

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou...

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer um if utilizando $this->uri->segment(1),
Exemplo:

```
<?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == 'login'){ ?><li><p class="navbar-btn">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">
  Cadastro
 </a></p></li><?php } } ?>
```